# Output of using 2 reducers in a word count program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

Let's say the key-value pairs with the keys “the”, “sound”, “is” are processed by reducer 1 and the key-value pairs with the keys “it”, “right”, “sounds” are processed by reducer 2.

What would be the outputs of the two reducers?

Would the output file of each reducer be sorted then combined then sorted again?

When the reducer receives them is it already sorted alphabetically so that reducer 1 receives “is”, “it”, “right” and reducer 2 receives “the”, “sound”, “sounds”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your queries:

1. Output of the reducer would be the word and count of its occurrence.
2. The output of reducer working on different keys are never combined. There is no such phase in mapreduce.
3. The output of the mapper is sorted and fed into reducer; but different reducer emits its output randomly and the output of the all the reducers is Not sorted again. There is no such phase in mapreduce.

Even though reducers are getting keys in sorted order, think each reducer running into a separate JVM and a separate process. They output the data without "knowing" that there are more reducer running.

Comment: regarding 2. what if reducers have worked on one or more common keys? is their output dynamically combined in that case?

Comment: for example, let's say, both reducers worked on the same words "w1", "w2", "w3". is there going to be 2 files each with its own counts for "w1", "w2", "w3" or they will be forwarded to reducer which will combine both and produce a single file?

Comment: Two different reducer working on the same key - How are you achieving it?

Comment: ah so you mean that every reducer will only process its own set of keys? i.e. there is no intersection between key sets of two different reducers? I thought that the mapper's output (after being shuffled and sorted) could be split like this: key1,key1,key2 goes to reducer1, and key2,key3,key3 to reducer2, key3,key4,key5 to reducer3 etc.

Comment: No, in normal scenario all 'values' emit by mapper against single 'key' are clubbed together in a collection. Each reducer get one key and all values as Collection<value>. This sometime can create skewed reducer, where one reducer got huge number of values and not able to finish (while other finished relatively earlier). There are ways to engage more than one reducer for a key, but that needs custom code. Hope you got it. Please do not forget to upvote the answer, if it helped.